# How to combine the data.tables inside one list into one data.table/data.frame

Tags: r, list, datatable

I am trying to combine all my rds results into one data frame.

right now, I have the following:

```
  1: data.table[37x16]
  2: data.table[37x16]
  3: data.table[37x16]
  4: data.table[37x16]
  5: data.table[37x16]       
212: data.table[37x16]
213: data.table[37x16]
214: data.table[37x16]
215: data.table[37x16]
216: data.table[37x16]
```

V1 is a list of 216.

each data. table inside the list has the same variables, and I am trying to make it into one data. table.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try `bind_rows(V1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `bind_rows` from `dplyr`, which combines by row.

Here's an example.

```
df1 <- tibble(x=1:3, y=4:6)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     1     4
2     2     5
3     3     6
```

```
df2 <- tibble(x=7:9, y=9:11)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     7     9
2     8    10
3     9    11
```

```
bind_rows(df1, df2)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     1     4
2     2     5
3     3     6
4     7     9
5     8    10
6     9    11
```

Since you have many data frames, you can put them in a list and then use `bind_rows`.

```
l <- list(df1, df2)

bind_rows(l)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     1     4
2     2     5
3     3     6
4     7     9
5     8    10
6     9    11
```

Comment: You could just use `bind_rows(l)`.

Comment: good suggestion, thanks! I updated my answer to use `bind_rows`.